# Rails nested form attribute not showing up in form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two models a permit and vehicle model. The vehicle table has a foreign key of the permit_id. I am trying to input the permit_id into vehicle table where the inputted license_number on the form equals to the license_number (which is not the primary key) in the vehicle table.

**vehicle.rb**

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
self.primary_key = :vehicle_id
belongs_to  :permit, optional: true
```

**permit.rb**

```
class Permit < ApplicationRecord
self.primary_key = :permit_id
has_one :vehicle
accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle
```

**permits_controller.rb**

```
class PermitsController < ApplicationController
...
def new
  @permit = Permit.new
  @vehicle = @permit.build_vehicle
end
params.require(:permit).permit(:permit_id.,...,vehicle_attributes: [:license_number])
```

**permit form**

```
<%= form_with(model: permit, local: true) do |form| %>
...
<div class="field">
  <% form.fields_for :vehicle do |f| %>
    License:
    <%= f.text_field :license_number, id: :vehicle_license_number %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My first problem is that my nested attribute license_number is not showing up at all in my field. I can see the div in the chrome elements, but the text field is not showing up. My second issue is how do I search in the vehicle table where license_number equals the license number inputted and then put the permit_id into the same row?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes your first issue, but you should leave the `id: :vehicle_license_number` part out and add an actual label with `f.label`.

To find the vehicle you could use `vehicle = Vehicle.find_by(license_number: permitted_params[:vehicle_attributes][:license_number]` and then save it using `@permit.update(vehicle: vehicle)`. That being said, I don't think you need to use `filed_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: Okay that sounds about right for second one. Unfortunately I can't even test it because I still can't figure out why the field for the form isn't showing up. Took out the id: :vehicle_license_number though.

Comment: Okay scratch that. I fixed it. I needed `<%= form.fields_for ... %>` and I didn't have that equal sign. Then just making sure. Do I put that 2nd part into the permit controller?

Comment: Yes, you do. As I above, try to not use `field_for`. Instead use `form.text_field` and just use the param for `find_by`. As you don't want to update `Vehicle`, just assign it to the permit, this would be the semantically better way of implementing this.